# How do I scrollTop to a div properly in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, scroll

I have:

```
<button class="contactButton">XYZ</button>
```

And when user will press this button I want my page to scroll down to specific div.

I tried this:

```
$(".contactButton").click(function () {
    $("html,body").animate({
    scrollTop: $(".specificDivClass").offset().top
    }, 1100);
});
```

Comment: Code looks fine to me. Can you check any error in console?

Comment: yea no errors, I also did console.log to check if script is loaded and it works.

Comment: Can you create fiddle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/psfLbo1n/

```js
$(".contactButton").click(function () {
    $("html,body").animate({
     scrollTop: $(".specificDivClass").offset().top
    }, 1100);
});
```

```css
.div1{
  height: 700px;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}

.specificDivClass{
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="contactButton">XYZ</button>

<div class="div1">

</div>

<div class="specificDivClass">

</div>
```

Comment: I guess class name you specified in jQuery is wrong, not matching to HTML thats why the scroll was not happening.. Please share you full HTML & CSS code..

Comment: I mean check this fiddle I uploaded above, it's not working but it looks the same as yours

Comment: @NeviJ... You missed jQuery library itself... Check the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hokert2u/1/ ... You need to add jQuery library using script tag.

Answer (score 1):

The problem most likely is misspelling the class name and/or not including the JavaScript to the HTML. You can try using ID instead of class to select the element you want to scroll to.